# True of false? If $\mathbb{E}(Y^2)=\infty$, then $Y^21_{|Y|\leqslant n}\overset{as}{\rightarrow}Y^2.$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

> Let $Y:\varOmega\to [-\infty,\infty]$ be a random variable such that $\mathbb{E}(Y^2)=\infty$. True of false? $Y^2\,1_{|Y|\leqslant n}\overset{as}{\rightarrow}Y^2.$

*Attempt*. For $\omega\in \varOmega$ s.t. $|Y(\omega)|<\infty$, for large $n$ we have 
$1_{|Y|\leqslant n}(\omega)=1$, so $Y^2(\omega)\,1_{|Y|\leqslant n}=Y^2(\omega)$. Since
$\mathbb{E}(Y^2)=\infty$, we may have $\mathbb{P}(Y^2=\infty)>0$, so we can not ignore $\omega$ s.t. $|Y(\omega)|=\infty$. In that case $1_{|Y|\leqslant n}(\omega)=0$ for all $n$ but $Y^2(\omega)\,1_{|Y|\leqslant n}(\omega)$ becomes an indeterminate form. How do we deal this case, in order to conclude convergence (or not)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The example $Y(\omega)=\infty$ for all $\omega$ shows that this is not true. In this case $Y^{2}1_{|Y| \leq n}=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Τhe convention $0\cdot \infty$ (that we consider when dealing with measures: $0\cdot \mu(X)=0\cdot \infty:=0$), also holds when working with measurable functions (also random variables), i.e. $0\cdot f(x)=0\cdot \infty:=0$?

Comment: @NikolaosSkout Yes, that convention is valid and  necessary thorughout measure theory.